# left-justified text for pli call

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I'm trying to make my test-bench more scalable and with a set of PLI functions that require a path name to an instance. I'm trying to avoid having to hardcore that paths. I can construct the path with the `$sformat`/`$sformatf` system tasks/functions. I tried defining the path as a SystemVerilog `string` type, but the PLI rejects it and I cannot change the PLI. The PLI does accept a reg array.

The challenge is the PLI requires left-justify text, but `$sformat`, `$sformatf` and `%s` are all right-justified.

```
 left-justified : "tb.vdut[10].inst9.sample_func       " // Desired
right-justified : "       tb.vdut[10].inst9.sample_func" // Actual
```

Example Function:

```
function void call(
    integer dut_id, inst_id,
    reg [CHAR_NUM-1:0] func_name,
    integer arg0, arg1, argN );

  reg [CHAR_NUM-1:0] path;
  $sformat(path,"tb.vdut[%0d].inst%0d.%0s", dut_id, inst_id, func_name );

  // Make path left-justified
  /* missing convert code here */

  $display("path:'%s', arg0:%0d, arg1:%0d, argN:%0d", path, arg0, arg1, argN );
  //$my_pli( path, arg0, arg1, argN );
endfunction : call
```

I have a self answer, but I'm looking for a cleaner solution. The while-loop can suck up a lot of CPU time if `CHANR_NUM` is big and the function `call` is executed often times.

Comment: How about a new PLI function that performs the conversion?

Comment: @Ari, I'd consider writing a my on left-justified PLI equivalent of `$sformat` if I had a the source C-code to `$sformat` or a tutorial of how to write a PLI with N arguments with unknown types.

Comment: Why the source code? I was thinking of passing the string to a PLI function which has access to library functions such as `sformat`, `std:setw`, `std:right` or even `Boost`.

Comment: @Ari, to me an ideal PLI solution would do the full formatting in one line on the sv side; otherwise it does not have an advantage over my two-step `$sformat` solution. Anyone who can show me how to write a PLI that works with this syntax: `$justifyleft_sformat ( output_var ,  format_string [ ,  list_of_arguments ] ) ;` will get the an best answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find another solution. First create a parameter for the format string. Use a parameter to the format evaluational only happens at compile/elaboration time, it will be static during simulation.

```
parameter FORMAT_LJUSTIFY = $sformatf("%%-%0ds",CHAR_NUM/8);
```

So if `CHAR_NUM` is 640, then `FORMAT_LJUSTIFY` will be `"%-80s"`, meaning the last 80 characters will be be left-justified.

Then use `$sformat(path, FORMAT_LJUSTIFY, path);`. It is recommended to use `$sformat` over `$sformatf` with reg arrays. Some simulators `$sformatf` as right justified, others wouldn't compile unless I did type casting. Type casting worked, but it is an extra.

Constraint: If the width of `path` must be `CHAR_NUM` else there will be leading and trailing white-space or chomped characters.

```
function void call(
    integer dut_id, inst_id,
    reg [CHAR_NUM-1:0] func_name,
    integer arg0, arg1, argN );

  reg [CHAR_NUM-1:0] path;
  $sformat(path,"tb.vdut[%0d].inst%0d.%0s", dut_id, inst_id, func_name );

  // Make path left-justified
  $sformat(path, FORMAT_LJUSTIFY, path);

  $display("path:'%s', arg0:%0d, arg1:%0d, argN:%0d", path, arg0, arg1, argN );
  //$my_pli( path, arg0, arg1, argN );
endfunction : call
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to convert right-justified to left-justified with a while-loop.

```
while(path[CHAR_NUM-1 -: 8] == " ") path <<= 8;
```

Limitation: Extra CPU overhead when `CHANR_NUM` is big and the function `call` is executed often times.

Current Solution:

```
function void call(
    integer dut_id, inst_id,
    reg [CHAR_NUM-1:0] func_name,
    integer arg0, arg1, argN );

  reg [CHAR_NUM-1:0] path;
  $sformat(path,"tb.vdut[%0d].inst%0d.%0s", dut_id, inst_id, func_name );

  // Make path left-justified
  while(path[CHAR_NUM-1 -: 8] == " ") path <<= 8; 

  $display("path:'%s', arg0:%0d, arg1:%0d, argN:%0d", path, arg0, arg1, argN );
  //$my_pli( path, arg0, arg1, argN );
endfunction : call
```